# Primefaces enable combobox after click on button

Tags: javascript, primefaces

Use case: I have a value in the edit form which is very important and should not be changed very often. I have decided to have it read only and have button "Change" on the side. After clicking on this button dialog with warning is dispalyed to the user and this readonly field is enabled for changing. (it is a selectOneMenu)

First attempt:

```
<p:selectOneMenu
                id="integrationCombo"
                value="#{backendBean.integration.backend}"
                widgetVar="backendIntegrationCombo"
                disabled="true">
    <f:selectItems
    value="#{backendBean.backends}"
    var="backend" itemValue="#{backend}"
    itemLabel="#{backend.name}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
<p:commandButton type="button"
     styleClass="inlineTableCellButton"
     onclick="backendIntegrationCombo.enable()"
     value="#{msg['button.change']}" />
```

This enables the combo box, but his value is not send to the server (this is due to disabled=true as i found)

My second attempt was to have editable boolean on the view scoped bean and
disable="#{!bean.editable}" and calling setEditable(true) with command button. This worked well, but for unknown reason now the save action on command button that submits the form stopped working.

Third attempt: render h:outputText with name and combobox (with hidden class) and after change button is clicked switch their hidden classes.

```
function changeBackend() {
    $("#backendName").addClass("hidden");
    $("#integrationCombo_input").parent().parent().removeClass("hidden");
}
```

That works fine too except one thing: after save is done - nothing is rendered (neither ouputText nor combo box)

Comment: Have you tried Inplace editor? Have a look at the third example http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/inplace.jsf

Comment: Nice, I did not know about the inplace component.

Comment: do you want the enable button also to submit (ajax or not) the data?

Comment: No, just enable the combo box. But i will probably use the inplace component suggested by @SerkanArıkuşu . Only thing i need to resolve is how to catch the dblclick event to show the warning.